# How can I make Windows 7's Start Menu look-and-feel like Windows XP's?

Tags: windows, gui, start-menu, control-panel

The reason for this is that I got accustomed to navigating the Start Menu with the keyboard, and I find that this is more efficient.

I tried importing the following .reg file, which helped with keyboard browsing and allowed me to avoid using the mouse...

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"StartMenuScrollPrograms"="NO"
"IntelliMenus"=dword:00000000
"CascadeControlPanel"="YES"
"CascadeNetworkConnections"="YES"
"CascadePrinters"="YES"
```

Normally, in Windows XP I only need to use the **[WinKey]** once and then only **[Up]/[Down] [Left]/[Right]** -- this is easy and intuitive.  But, in Windows 7 I also need use the **[TAB]** key which is far away from the navigation keys.

In Windows XP all the items are also in a single menu.

How can I get the above Windows XP behavior for my Start Menu?

**PS**. Thanks for answer. I stay at **classicshell** which can be downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Classic Shell](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/classicshell.html), it seems to do what you want.

Comment: That I want! Excellent. +1